# It is possible convert part of this code to improve speed?

Tags: python, cython, numba

I am new here,

Please, I need help to convert part of this code to anything to improve speed, and still compatibility with python programs to use this function. It is possible to improve speed with this?

On my system, a image colored 224x224 consumes 360 milliseconds to finish.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
# original code https://github.com/verhovsky/squircle/blob/master/squircle.py

import cv2
import math
import time
import numpy

_epsilon = 0.0000000001

def _sgn(x):
    if x == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    if x < 0:
        return -1.0
    return 1.0

def _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(coordinate, max_value):
    return coordinate / max_value * 2 - 1

def _one_coordinates_to_pixels(coordinate, max_value):
    return (coordinate + 1) / 2 * max_value

def _stretch_square_to_disc(x, y):
    if (abs(x) < _epsilon) or (abs(y) < _epsilon):
        return x, y

    x2 = x * x
    y2 = y * y
    hypotenuse_squared = x * x + y * y

    reciprocal_hypotenuse = 1.0 / math.sqrt(hypotenuse_squared)

    multiplier = 1.0

    if x2 > y2:
        multiplier = _sgn(x) * x * reciprocal_hypotenuse
    else:
        multiplier = _sgn(y) * y * reciprocal_hypotenuse

    return x * multiplier, y * multiplier

def _transform(inp):
    result = numpy.zeros_like(inp)
    for x, row in enumerate(inp):

        unit_x = _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(x, len(inp))

        for y, _ in enumerate(row):
            unit_y = _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(y, len(row))

            try:
                uv = _stretch_square_to_disc(unit_x, unit_y)
                if uv is None:
                    continue
                u, v = uv

                u = _one_coordinates_to_pixels(u, len(inp))
                v = _one_coordinates_to_pixels(v, len(row))

                result[x][y] = inp[math.floor(u)][math.floor(v)]
            except IndexError:
                pass

    return result

# -- load and test

img = cv2.imread('circle.png')

elapsed = round(time.time() * 1000)
squareImage = _transform(img[0:224, 0:224])
print(str(round(time.time() * 1000) - elapsed)+' ms to squareImage')

cv2.imshow('square', squareImage)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expected to try convert this code or part of this to anything more fasted, may be CUDA to run direct on GPU, or NUMBA, Cython, lib etc...

Answer (score 2):

I've used `numba` to decorate the functions (removed the `_sgn` and used `np.sign`, removed the `try..except` - is it needed?):

```py
import math
import time

import cv2
import numpy
from numba import njit

_epsilon = 0.0000000001


@njit
def _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(coordinate, max_value):
    return coordinate / max_value * 2 - 1


@njit
def _one_coordinates_to_pixels(coordinate, max_value):
    return (coordinate + 1) / 2 * max_value


@njit
def _stretch_square_to_disc(x, y):
    if (abs(x) < _epsilon) or (abs(y) < _epsilon):
        return x, y

    x2 = x * x
    y2 = y * y
    hypotenuse_squared = x * x + y * y

    reciprocal_hypotenuse = 1.0 / np.sqrt(hypotenuse_squared)

    multiplier = 1.0

    if x2 > y2:
        multiplier = np.sign(x) * x * reciprocal_hypotenuse
    else:
        multiplier = np.sign(y) * y * reciprocal_hypotenuse

    return x * multiplier, y * multiplier


@njit
def _transform(inp):
    result = numpy.zeros_like(inp)
    for x, row in enumerate(inp):
        unit_x = _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(x, len(inp))

        for y, _ in enumerate(row):
            unit_y = _pixel_coordinates_to_unit(y, len(row))

            uv = _stretch_square_to_disc(unit_x, unit_y)
            if uv is None:
                continue

            u, v = uv

            u = _one_coordinates_to_pixels(u, len(inp))
            v = _one_coordinates_to_pixels(v, len(row))

            result[x][y] = inp[math.floor(u)][math.floor(v)]

    return result


# -- load and test

img = cv2.imread("circle.png")

# warm jit
# this is needed to let numba do the JIT optimizations
# if you run the the function "cold", the running time will be larger

# you can use compile-ahead-of-time
# https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html

squareImage = _transform(img[0:224, 0:224])

elapsed = time.perf_counter_ns()
squareImage = _transform(img[0:224, 0:224])
print(str((time.perf_counter_ns() - elapsed) / 1000) + " us to squareImage")

cv2.imwrite("shashed.png", squareImage)
```

---

On my computer (AMD 5700X) it prints:

```
528.596 us to squareImage

# without using numba:
# 47928.774 us to squareImage
```

Images used:

#### `circle.png`

[image]

#### the result

[image]

---

Comment: Many Thnaks Andrej Kesely! It is 80x fast now!!

Comment: _sgn is better without numba. Using np.sign without numba the time is 983 ms to squareImage

Comment: @AlexandreBensi Yes, without numba use `_sgn` (`np.sign` has overhead). But when you use `numba`, it will optimize the `np.sign`

Comment: Using casting can be certainly faster than `math.floor` (which needs to consider negative values which are impossible here). Reducing the precision and using fast-math can certainly improve further performance since `1.0 / np.sqrt(hypotenuse_squared)` can be computed in one instruction and only few cycle on x86-64 CPUs (from 32 cycle of latency to only 4 cycles, and from 10 cycles of throughput to only 1 cycle, that is 10x faster). Fast-math can also precompute 1/x and use multiplication by constants (like `1.0/len(inp)` for example). For integers, int32 divisions are faster than 64-bit ones.